# Django-rest-pandas TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have created a PandasSimpleView which overrides the 'get_data' method to return a Pandas Dataframe.

I have put the following renderer_classes inside the PandasSimpleView method :

renderer_classes = (PandasHTMLRenderer, PandasCSVRenderer, PandasJSONRenderer, PandasTextRenderer,)

I am able to render CSV, text and JSON successfully except HTML. My assumption is i dont need a template to be able to render the HTML if i am using PandasSimpleView since Django-REST-pandas framework do not require template but views and url.

So, why am i still receiving an exception TemplateDoesNotExist?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5zAb.png)

Answer (score 0):

class QuestionStats (PandasSimpleView):

```
renderer_classes = (PandasHTMLRenderer, PandasCSVRenderer, PandasJSONRenderer, PandasTextRenderer,)

def get_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    curr_slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug', None)
    data = get_question_stats(curr_slug)
    return data

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = self.get_data(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return Response(data, template_name='questions/questionstats.html')
```

The problem is resolved, by overriding the 'get' method and returning Response with the template name location.